# Yellow Paper Section 4:1 (6) and (7) explanation help needed:

Tags: go-ethereum, yellow-paper

Can anyone please explain this (6) and (7) and what does "element-wise transformation means"?
 [image: Trie function]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be:

for **(6):** The top-level function is the TRIE which accepts a 
          element-wise eval function which we define as level L
          L accepts two functions KEC, RLP

for **(7):** so **Li -> ( KEC(ki), RLP(vi) )** and the universal representation of this function which applies to all elements would be:

```
       L[I]* = (KEC(k), RLP(v))
```

Please do let me know if I am on the right track here.