# Questions about the Yellowpaper notations

Tags: yellow-paper

Got some questions on notations (Page 4)-

1. [What does function/tuple L represent?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/yellow-paper-section-41-6-and-7-explanation-help-needed) Also, what are its subscripted subparts? (Equations - 6, 7, 9)
2. What does [image: circle with a line passing through] mean? (Equation - 9)
3. What do these symbols mean - [image: pencil tip], [image: V] and [image: inverted V] ? (Equations - 11, 12)

The names of the symbols would be a help too. Thanks a Lot for your time and efforts.

[image: Yellow paper Page 4]

Comment: 2. It denotes `{}`, aka *the empty set*.

Comment: 3. The mean respectively: For every, Or, And.